# Intensely vs Intensively

Tags: word-difference

WikiDiff https://wikidiff.com/intensely/intensively says that both are adverbs and only have the difference that "**intensely**" means '*in an intense manner*' while "**intensively**" means '*in an intensive way*'. I cannot understand how this word is used in their example :

- An **intensely** private man, he kept chit-chat to a minimum.

How and when to use the word "**intensely**"?

Comment: No, it is not an adjective; it modifies the adjective **private** and refers to the degree to which he guards his privacy.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How silly of me. Indeed, it is an adverb, for "private" is the adjective. I still can't understand when and how to use "intensely".

Comment: For "intensely," your link says, "In an intense manner." Not "intensive".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Intensive** has a temporal component: a lot is crammed into a little span of time, whereas **intense**  merely means "very great" and **intensely** means "to a very great degree" or "in a very concentrated or focused manner" without a temporal component.

> This new paint can withstand intense heat.
>
> The students in this international business program undergo intensive foreign-language training.
>
> Some people find the deletion of comments below an answer intensely irritating.
>
> She studied French intensively before taking a year at the Sorbonne.

P.S. OP asks in a comment if **push intensely** is idiomatic. It isn't. The words **intense** and **intensely** refer to a *concentrated* or *focused* energy. When you hold a magnifying glass up to the sunlight and it is focused to a point of searing white, the light can be said to be *intense* or to shine *intensely* on that focal point. A **push**, at least in the literal sense (i.e. a shove), does not involve a concentrated or focused application of energy but a broadly applied effort.

> They pushed intensely on the door to get it to budge. <sup>no</sup>
>
> The movie hero gazed intensely into the villain's eyes. <sup>yes</sup>

Comment: That means "we should study intensely" will be incorrect?

Comment: Still both "you should push intensely" and "you should push intensively" are correct?

Comment: Let me see if I can explain why "push intensely" is not an apt usage.  But I need a second cup of coffee.

Comment: No, @SovereignSun, neither _push intensely_ nor _push intensively_ works, for different reasons. _Push intensely_ doesn't work, because _intense_ is not usually used for physical force. _Push intensively_ doesn't work because _intensive_ is not usually used for a single action, but for a lot of actions or expreriences purposefully packed into a short time.

Comment: _Study intensely_ is better than _push intensely_, but it still doesn't quite fit. I think that _intense_ tends not to be used for actions or activities, but for states and qualities (there is a significant exception for words like "exercise" and "workout", which frequently do cooccur with _intense_)

Comment: @ColinFine Oh, it's all so strange. So we "study intensively" but we "hate something intensely"?

Comment: @SovereignSun I believe you are getting poor advice. I see nothing wrong with pushing or studying *intensely*. In fact, I can study both *intensely* and *intensively*. They mean different things. But they can certainly both be used. I hear *intensely* used this way all the time.

Comment: Jason, if you were to say *He pushed intensely against the door*, I'd think you were not a native speaker.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, that would mean that none of the millions of people where I live are native speakers either. It may just not be used where *you* live.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: Ain't no Ngram attestations.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: And I also said "in the literal sense" of **push** (i.e. "shove").  I don't doubt that when **push** is used figuratively to mean "lobby for" or "devote energy and effort towards achieving a goal" or even "goad (with words, not physically)" or "forcefully encourage" that you'd find **intensely** used as an adverb.

Comment: The iWeb corpus (14 billion words) has precisely one attestation of "push intensely" (with any form of the verb "push") and that is a figurative use: "they often push intensely for plea bargains". The same one instance is in the NOW corpus, and there are none in the GloWbE corpus.